# React JS: Event bubbles also when no event attached

Tags: reactjs

First, please look at the following demo code:

```
function AComponent() {

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '150px', border: '1px solid red' }} onClick={() => { console.log('container 1 called'); }}>
      <div style={{ width: '100px', border: '1px solid blue' }} onClick={() => { console.log('container 2 called'); }}>
        <p style={{ fontSize: '16px', width: '75px', border: '1px solid teal' }}>
          this is a text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the `P` tag has no event attached, though, on the console there will be written:

```
container 2 called
container 1 called
```

I think, even I attach an event or not, for every HTML element, all possible events for that element are attached by default.

In **react-native**, the scenario is different. There are no such things like this.

Actually, I want to

1. disable the mentioned behavior of Default Event Attachment.
2. disable Event Bubble For every Event by default.

**is it possible in react?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's any way to disable event bubbling completely by default.

What you can do is to stop event bubbling using `e.stopPropagation()` on the second onClick action.

Maybe you can implement a HOF(Higher Order Function) for yourself which get's a callback action, and inside that HOF you can use `e.stopPropagation()` and then call your passed callback.
in this way you can use it everywhere in your code without repeating it.

Your HOF:

```
const stopPropagationAndCallAction = (e, callback) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   callback(e);
}
```

Your Component:

```
return(
  <div>
    <p onClick={(e) => { stopPropagationAndCallAction(e, yourDesiredCallback) }}>Hello</p>
  </div>
 )
```

Comment: can you give an example in detail (about how Higher Order Function may solve this issue)?

Answer (score 1):

I am correct, what you want is that the onClick of the p tag should not call their parent elements.
This can be done in react using the stopPropagation method, which stops the bubbling up to the parent elements of event calls.

Example -

```
<p onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>Hello</p>
```

Thank you
Hope this helped :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But your solution is not acceptable to me, because, I have to attach event and call `stopPropagation` for each and every element, even I want or not.